# .htaccess or symbolic link (symlink)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with multiple folders and I was trying to fix them in my .htaccess. After a little while, I have a big .htaccess with rules that conflicts.

Now every time I want to add a folder I have to add it to the .htaccess.

I did some research and I found out I can create symbolic link instead, so no more .htaccess

In both solution I have to create or modify something so for me its the same result at the end but is it a better practice to create instead symbolic link ?

Comment: The symbolic link you are creating is a link to the .htaccess in each case? I am wondering if there is not something you can do directly in the http.conf apache configuration file. I understand there are performance advantages to t hat.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Symbolic links are faster yes (like Aki said) but here's my thoughts on this.

if you have images, css or js files then you don't need to rewrite or create symbolic links. You can use the full URL (eg `/images/...`) or use a common domain like `i.domain.com` (or anything you want) and refer all your JS, Images and CSS there. Eg: `i.domain.com/logo.jpg` or `js.domain.com/site.js`.

This way, you never have to think about rewriting rules or create links you might forget one day.

This one is very easy to manage and maintain if you need to add images, change js or update your CSS since you only have one point of entry and automatically everything be updated.

Answer (score 28):

use symblink, .htaccess has to be proccesed by apache whereas the symblink are proccess by the OS which is faster.

creating 100 rules vs 100 symblink, if the rule you looking for is at the last you will have to parse all of them then use the one you need.